# Pandas Panel .dropna behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array [here](http://pastebin.com/0pegUBbp) that describes some data in a pandas `Panel`.  I would like to drop the `NaN`s (which are rows along the major axis) and leave the data intact but it seems that calling `.dropna(axis=1, how='any')` will discard one row from the item that has 10 good rows and calling `.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` will leave one row of `NaN`s on the item that has 9 good rows.  How can I dispose of the `NaN`s without loosing data?

Comment: If your question still makes sense if you reduce your data set to, say, four or five rows, please do so.

Comment: You still need to have the same dimensions in the two items of your panel. So because in the second item you have 4 NaN rows and in the first 3, you will always have to either keep one NaN row in the second item or throw away one non-NaN row in the first item. If you don't want that, then you have to work in two seperate dataframes so they can end up with a different number of rows.

Comment: @joris  Ah, right and I'll have to make sets of panels for each dimension type and work across all of them.  If you want to offer your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to have the same dimensions in the two items of your panel. So because in the second item you have 4 NaN rows and in the first 3, you will always have to either keep one NaN row in the second item or throw away one non-NaN row in the first item. If you don't want that, then you have to work in two seperate dataframes so they can end up with a different number of rows.